# Change Git server path

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 system with Git installed. I use it as a Git server for some of my code projects. To get my repository I currently have to use the Repository URL `ssh://myserver/home/myuser/codeproject.git`. Is there any way to change this path to `ssh://myserver/codeproject.git`?

Comment: Surely you're not doing this often enough to matter?

Comment: Why? Is it very difficult to achieve that? I surely could put all my Git projects into the root ("/"), but this wouldn't be very elegant.

Comment: Yes, I believe it's difficult to achieve on the SSH driver. You're correct that putting them in the root would be a bad idea. I'm asking why you're typing the repository URL so often it's worth changing for you.